# Angular Directive not updating DOM on first load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm using a directive to implement different D3 graphs using ng-repeat on an array of data. At the end of creating a D3 elements I calculate the height of the graph and update the parent DIV accordingly.

When opening the page the first time the height of the parent div is not properly updated. When switching views to another category everything works fine.

The repeat is pretty straight forward where the "grid-item" is supposed to be updated

```
<li ng-repeat="var in cards.variables" class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item" grid-block data="var"></div>
</li>
```

This is the directive I use for creating D3 elements. I've tried using scope.$apply() after rendering but this results in $digest already in progress. Using $timeout to render the graph doesn't seem to have any effect either.

```
.directive('gridBlock', function(d3Service, WrapService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {
        // Set dimensions
        var width = 100;
        var height = 0;

        // Create d3 element
        var svg = d3.select(element[0])
        .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width)

        scope.render = function(data) {
          // Remove previous render
          svg.selectAll('*').remove();

          var header = svg.append('text')
            .text(data.value);

          height += header.node().getBBox().height;

          switch(data.variable.type) {
           case 1:
              // Absolute
              var body = svg.append('rect')
                .attr('y', height)
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', 100)
                .attr('fill', '#E6E7E8');

              height += body.node().getBBox().height + 10;
              break;
          case 2:
            ...
            break;
          }

          var desc = svg.append('text')
            .attr('x', 0)
            .attr('y', height)
            .text(data.variable.label  + ' in ' + data.year)

          height += desc.node().getBBox().height;
          width = desc.node().getBBox().width;

          // Set dimensions on svg, width only when +100
          svg.attr('height', height);
          if (width > 100) {
            svg.attr('width', width);
          }

          // Set dimensions on parent
          element.css({'width': width + 'px', 'height': height + 'px'});
        };

        // Render visualisation
        scope.render(scope.data);

      });
    }
  };
})
```

See pictures for examples:

[Graph elements with incorrect height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6ZNK.png)

[Graph elements with correctly updated height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgnAF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to solve the problem itself but found a solution for my project by using CSS columns. All elements are properly loaded and it actually now after changing the height through D3.